# Django's clean DateField failing for no reason

Tags: django, django-forms, datefield

Every few requests people would get errors while using the form on my site
on the DateField, even though it seems their input is fine

```
birthday = forms.DateField(widget=MyDateInput(attrs={ 'min': (datetime.now()- timedelta(days=100*365)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),  'max': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 'class': 'required' ,'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'required': 'no'}))
```

I use this code to send myself an email when they fail on this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
def clean(self):
    if self._errors and 'birthday' in self._errors and len(self._errors)==1:
        mail_admins("BAD Birthday register",str(self._errors) + '\n' + str(self.request))
```

this is an example of an email i get:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>birthday<ul class="errorlist"><li>Introduzca una fecha válida.</li></ul></li></ul>
<WSGIRequest
path:/community/register/,
GET:<QueryDict: {u'bundle_id': [u'com.test.test'], u'ver': [u'2.4']}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {u'first_name': [u'Mol'], u'last_name': [u'Mol'], u'gender': [u'f'], u'user_type': [u'3'], u'birthday': [u'2015-02-22'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'fmx6QGTTkE2SbBzxlsKOwfPjjb4ztvjk'], u'password': [u'*******'], u'email': [u'some@email.com']}>,
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '175',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'fmx6QGTTkE2SbBzxlsKOwfPjjb4ztvjk',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT':             'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'es-es',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=fmx6QGTTkE2SbBzxlsKOwfPjjb4ztvjk;     NREUM=h=1424188941317&r=281636&p=281636;     __utma=175034791.2027745757.1424184041.1424184041.1424188639.2;     __utmb=175034791.7.10.1424188639; __utmc=175034791; __utmt=1; __utmz=175034791.1424184041.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
 'HTTP_FORWARDED_REQUEST_URI': '/community/register/?ver=2.4',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.test.it',
 'HTTP_HTTPS': 'on',
 'HTTP_HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'https',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'https://www.test.it',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://www.test.it/community/register/?    ver=2.4&bundle_id=com.27dv.tinytap',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X)     AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A465',
```

other requests with similarly formatted dates have succeeded,
plus if i fake a request  like this with postman, it goes through.

**EDIT:**
this seems to be happening only when

```
'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'es-es',
```

Comment: The example you gave has a `birthday` of `2015-02-22`—isn't that outside the maximum date you gave in your validator? Don't you want to reject birthdates in the future?

Comment: yes but some other dates like "1969-11-13" "2011-02-17" gave same error